# @SkipSerialization

Tags: json, vraptor, gson, referência-circular

Estou com um problema para serializar minhas classes. Estou com um problema de referencia circular, então estou tentando tratar isso adicionando a anotação @SkipSerialization na classe para evitar que a mesma seja serializada. No entanto, isso parece não estar funcionando. Estou utilizando o vRaptor4, o qual utiliza o Gson para serializar.

Esta é minha estrutura:

```
public class GrupoCampoBean implements Serializable {

    private final List<GrupoCampo> grupoCampos;

    public GrupoCampoBean(List<GrupoCampo> gruposCampos) {
        this.grupoCampos = gruposCampos;
    }
}
```

Minha entidade principal:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_grupo_campo")
public class GrupoCampo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "grupoCampo")
    private List<GrupoCampoContextoPropriedade> contextos;

}
```

Entidade GrupoCampoContextoPropriedade a qual possui referencia circular

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_grupo_campo_contexto_propriedade")
public class GrupoCampoContextoPropriedade implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "visivel_listagem", nullable = false)
    private Boolean visivelListagem;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean obrigatorio;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "visivel_filtro", nullable = false)
    private Boolean visivelFiltro;

    @JoinColumn(name = "cod_contexto", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Contexto contexto;

    **@SkipSerialization**
    @JoinColumn(name = "cod_grupo_campo", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private GrupoCampo grupoCampo;
}
```

Após realizar uma consulta, repasso a List para o método de serialização:

```
@Path("/{modulo}/grupo-campos")
public void getGrupoCampos(String modulo, String contexto) {
    try {
        toJson(grupoCampoService.getGrupoCamposModulo(getCliente(), modulo, contexto));
    } catch (MurphException ex) {
        tratarException(ex);
    }
}
```

Por fim, para serializar utilizo o seguinte:

```
protected void toJson(Object object, String... exclude) {
    result.use(json()).withoutRoot().from(object).recursive().exclude(exclude).serialize();
}
```

Tentei também utilizar @XmlTransient, mas não deu certo.

Obrigado pessoal.

Comment: Tentou tirar o `recursive()` e incluir as listas que você deseja com o `include()`?